# Is it a good practice to check referer in the server-side form submission handler?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, csrf

I am doing a Java web site. I hope to make the web site safer.

In my web site, all the forms are supposed (by design) to be opened in a page through a GET link from my website. I hope to check whether the referer is my web site in my server-side form submission handler. The idea is to avoid taking data from attacker-locally-generated form submission.

I feel that the key to this approach is whether the referer the server detects  is reliable.

I understand that there are other ways to improve security. Let's just focus on the approach in my post.

Thanks for any input!

**UPDATE**

Specifically, I am doing a Spring MVC web site. I am using an interceptor to examine all traffic, especially the form submission.

Comment: For specifically the referer, I'll agree with the answer below that it's not a good way to implement security.  It's too easily spoofed because if the attacker can figure out that it's a validating piece of information, they can just always use it because it never changes.  If you want to get really creative, you can generate a new token each time your server creates that form page, remember that token on the server side, and then have the form send that token as part of the submission to match it with the stored token in the server.  It's still not fool proof though.

Comment: subdigit, I know of the token approach. Thanks for mentioning it. I haven't tried the token approach yet because at this moment I am trying to maintain as little session data as possible on the server-side. Again, thanks!

Comment: @subdigit: Not always as easy as that. Remember than in a CSRF attack, the attacker does not have direct control of the headers. Check [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33889773/413180). Agreed though that `referer` isn't the most reliable way - however, it is better than nothing.

Comment: "Better than nothing". Like that!

Comment: Definitely lots to consider given there are so many vectors of attack.  But in the context of the question which was to try to use the referer header as a means of identifying if someone came from the server's website or not, it maybe only one step better than nothing.  But if @curious1 is going to do *something*, there are much better things to try than to rely on the referer header, especially in the context of the question.

Comment: @subdigit, thanks for your follow-up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not reliable. Some browsers may allow removing the referrer, or might not send it at all.  And a naughty person can easily just add the referrer to the requests, so by itself it will not give any extra security except from random people trying random things.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best way, but [referer checking can help prevent Cross Site Request Forgery attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header):

> Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own
>   browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack. Checking the
>   referer is a commonly used method of preventing CSRF on embedded
>   network devices because it does not require a per-user state.
>
> [snip]
>
> ...checking the referer is considered to be a weaker from of CSRF
>   protection. For example, open redirect vulnerabilities can be used to
>   exploit GET-based requests that are protected with a referer check and
>   some organizations or browser tools remove referrer headers as a form
>   of data protection.

Remember here that the attacker is not the one sitting at the keyboard - it is harder for them to spoof the referer from the victim's machine.

The strongest way of preventing CSRF though is the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern).